# Calculating discounts by rounding up and not giving more than intended

Tags: c#, loops

Here is the scenario.

I am writing code for applying discounts and I am having all sorts of trouble.

Let us assume that my order has the following and as a sales rep I have decided to give the customer a discount of £23.47 for this order.

I have 3 line items, two of them costing £150.00 and one costing £10.00. The total value of order is £310.00

So, I need to calculate the %discount for each line item (because, the external interfaces cannot cope with an order level discount, but only a line item discount). Also, the external interfaces can cope with only one decimal in the Discount% field.

Logic:

1. I calculate the total (before discounting) of the order. It comes to £310.00.
2. I work out the discount amount as a percentage of the total order value, i.e., £23.47 / £310.00

The discount% works out to be 7.570967741935484%. However, this needs to be rounded off to 7.6%. If I do so, what happens is the discount amount is higher for each line item. The discount amount for each line item is higher. And the total discount I end up giving is £23.56 which is £0.08 more than what I intended to give, £23.47.

Each line item should get a discount of £11.36, £11.36 and £0.76 but I end up giving £11.40, £11.40 and £0.76.

What I need is to work out the "error" that I get in my rounding off for each line item and compensate for the error in the item which is least priced to which it can be applied so that the discount price is as close to what I intended to give (it should, however, be rounded up and NEVER rounded down).

When applying the discount to each line item, do I have to "remember" the remainder discount amount which needs to be applied?

Pseudo Code as follows.

```
iterating through each line item
//first line item where I have given more discount than intended. 4p more. So, the remaining discount is not £12.11 but actually £12.07
//Calculate the discount% for remaining line items, i.e., 
//And, I am confused :-)
```

What would be the best way of doing this?

PS: Not sure if this needs to be here. But feel free to point me in the right direction or delete it if not applicable to the SE sites.

Comment: Why do you have to round to 1 decimal place on the discount?

Comment: Ignore this question. Not quite, programming related but more of pseudo code and logic. Marking it for deletion.

Comment: Mathew: Because, a system which interfaces with my system can cope with only one decimal place.

Comment: *"Also, the external interfaces can cope with only one decimal in the Discount% field. "*

Comment: Sorry I thought you meant to calculate the new discounted item price, not sending in the original price and the discount percentage.  I think it would be acceptable to talk to whoever asked you to use this API and say it will not support exactly what they want to do.  I think a scenario that will be problematic is performing a return on one individual item, that will cause the calculated discount to become out of sync with the entire order.

Comment: Don't attempt to store the discount % for each item.  Just calculate the discount amount, store the % internal to the code ( i.e. ( total discount % / number of items ) then calculate the discount amount for each item.  You would apple any other additional VAT, Sales Taxes, ect, after the fact.

Comment: Needs to be migrated to math.stackoverflow. (Flagging to bring the mods' attention.)

Comment: @Matthew: I wish, I could do that. Unfortunately, it is a system written when mankind rubbed stones together to discover fire and there is no hope of changing the API. In fact, it is not the API that is a problem, it is the other system which is a problem. Any schema changes to the other system is a strict no-no.

Comment: Oh, cannot flag my own comment above :( Can anyone do it for me?

Comment: @Ramhound: The other system, unfortunately, cannot accept the discounted amount. It can cope only with the line item discount percent.

Answer (score 0):

Do not round to 7.6%, work out an exact(ish) discount for each item using the full 7.570967741935484%.

This will give you a fractional result. Round up if necessary but either way work out your fractional error.

On your next item, **add the error from the previous item** before deciding how to round.

Repeat.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it's not always possible to achieve if you are constrained to the discount percentage with not more than 1 decimal place.

Imagine the following input: you are selling only one item, which costs £1000, and you want to give 1p discount. So, either you give 0.1% discount (resulting in the whole £1), or 0% (resulting in no discount at all).

In fact, the discount you may give can be expressed in 1/1000th of the smallest item price (from 1 up to 1000), possibly adding discounts from the second smallest item price etc.

So, sometimes you cannot achieve getting the amount of discount you really want -- what can be done in this case?

A simple approach would be to try combination of different discounts. Obviously, you can sell each item for P (its normal price), 999/1000 * P, 998/1000 * P, ... 0/1000 * P. So, you can try to find a coefficient for each item, which makes the total amount as close to the needed sum as possible. This simple idea would be unfortunately too slow if the number of items in the purchase is big.

(A note aside: if we were not constrained with only positive discounts, we could actually do the following trick: find the greatest common divisor of all the item prices, and having it, we could easily make up any price with the precision of GCD/1000.)

Note about negative discounts: imagine that you are *allowed* to give negative discounts as well. For example, you can give a discount of -1%, resulting in the customer paying 1% *more* for the item. This way you can achieve more accurate approximation. Example: if you've got 2 items, which cost £1000 and £990 respectively, and you want to give the total discount of 1p: You can achieve this by giving discount of 0.1% for the first item and -0.1% for the second item, so the customer pays £1000 * 99.9% = £999 for the first item and £990 * 100.1% = £990.99 for the second item. Altogether it's £1989.99, which is exactly 1p discount from £1990. One couldn't achieve such a precision with just positive discounts, you see?

Comment: In this case, I would have to give them £1 because when you round up that is the value you get. For the benefit of customer, always round up.

Comment: @Magic: I would say your question is better suited for [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thought so...was not too sure. Can someone please migrate it?

Comment: I agree. Sometimes we cannot achieve getting the amount, and in that case, we would have give the customer a penny or two extra.

Comment: @Magic: flagged your comment so that someone could migrate the question.

Comment: I could not understand your note. And, what do you mean by positive discounts?

Comment: @Magic: expanded the answer, included more explanation about negative discounts.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a discount percentage to each line, you can't then apply the same discount percentage to the total price and get the same answer because of roundings. You need to sum the discounted prices on each line to get the total.

I have seen this done so many times on a number of systems and there is only the one way to get it to work. Each line has the correct price/value so you need to sum them up.